# Scala print help commands

Tags: scala

I am want to print help commands for my command line app.
Usually it looks like:

> Usage: ./run.sh [command] [arguments]
>
> -abc [filename]                       some description
>
> -def [filename]                       some description

and I would like to have those descriptions always align to the right, so tabs difference between command argument and desciption can vary.

is there some simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried? Anyways, the simplest (best?) approach would be using a library for defining and parsing those commands which usually provide this help text out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

A library like https://github.com/bkirwi/decline or https://github.com/scopt/scopt gives you command-line parsing and features for emitting help on those options.